# How to get the full name of an object?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

What should `www`, `xxx`, `yyy` and `zzz` be in the following?

```
window.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

App.module('ContactMgr.Detail', function (Detail, App, ... ) {
  Detail.Layout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
      console.log( www );   // prints 'Layout'
      console.log( xxx );   // prints 'Detail'
      console.log( yyy );   // prints 'App.ContactMgr.Detail'
      console.log( zzz );   // prints 'App.ContactMgr.Detail.Layout'  
                            // (if not concatenating yyy and www)
    };
  });
)};
```

Comment: where is Detail.Layout initialized?

Comment: @aktiv-coder   in App.Controller `Marionette.Controller.extend ...`.

Comment: Example use is: having all different Layouts (Layout1, Layout2, ...) extending from one base class `App.Layout` which when initialized prints 'Layout1 initialized' etc.

Comment: Where are `www`, `xxx`, etc defined?  I see where you call them, but there is no definition...

Comment: @AlexZ  this IS the question: how to print those names as in comments?

Comment: They're placeholders, gotcha

Comment: The name references the "class" but the "class" can have many names. What would you expect to happen if you said `var Pancakes = Detail.Layout`? If your views need to know their names then you'll have to do it yourself by adding things to the `extend` call.

Comment: @muistooshort  I agree on multiple names,  but since `instanceof` knows the instance name, I guess some names have been hidden in objects? [demo](http://jsbin.com/busorumuno/4/edit?js,console)

Comment: But you're not giving `instanceof` a name, you're saying `o instanceof value` where `value` is **not** a name, it is the "class" itself.